# How to access cross-domain iframe content? (Upload file cross-domain)

Tags: javascript, http, iframe, cors

Is it possible, with CORS headers, to make the content of an iframe accessible cross-domain?

I have tried the simple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` headers but that is apparently not enough. I can't control the form submission itself, so perhaps that is an issue (I can't setup any kind of CORS request).

Note my goal is to upload a file cross-domain and get the result of that submission. The iframe approach is a common file upload one, so I'm trying that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get direct access to the DOM.

One page needs to listen for `message` events, and the other needs to [send them using `postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

```
addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(evt) {
    var message = evt.data;
    if (message === "success") {
        alert("yay!");
    }
}
```

and

```
top.postMessage("success", "*");
```